# Android: String array

Tags: android, arrays

I have a game activity about different alphabet are randomly available user would select some of them that are making a correct word.
i made the string array of word which is answer
but i want to knew how to display this answer word alphabets and adding some randomly other alphabet as a confusion?
like taking the answer for example [World] and divid it's alphabet like that [W , L, D , O]  AND make them randomly displayed and the player choose from them ?

```
TextView guessItTimer;
CountDownTimer timer;
Random r;
String currentWord;

private int presCounter = 0;
private int maxPresCounter = 4;
private String[] keys = {"R", "I", "B", "D", "X"};
String dictionary[] = {
        "remember",
        "hungry",
        "crying",
        "sour",
        "sleep",
        "awesome",
        "Seven",
        "color",
        "began",
        "appear",
        "weight",
        "language"
};
TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
Animation smallbigforth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guess_it);

    guessItTimer = findViewById(R.id.guessItTimer);
    smallbigforth = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.smallbigforth);

    keys = shuffleArray(keys);
    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(( findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, findViewById(R.id.et_guess));
    }
    maxPresCounter = 4;

    resetTimer();
}

//CountdownTimer
void resetTimer() {
   timer = new CountDownTimer(30150, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            guessItTimer.setText(String.valueOf(l / 1000));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(GuessItActivity.this, "Time is over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(GuessItActivity.this, BossFinalActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
private String[] shuffleArray(String[] ar) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        String a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
    return ar;
}
private void addView(LinearLayout viewParent, final String text, final EditText editText) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    linearLayoutParams.rightMargin = 30;

    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    textView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgpink));
    textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setFocusable(true);
    textView.setTextSize(32);

    textQuestion = findViewById(R.id.textQuestionBoss);
    textScreen = findViewById(R.id.gametitle);
    textTitle =  findViewById(R.id.Ammo);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(presCounter < maxPresCounter) {
                if (presCounter == 0)
                    editText.setText("");
                editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + text);
                textView.startAnimation(smallbigforth);
                textView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300);
                presCounter++;
                if (presCounter == maxPresCounter)
                    doValidate();
            }
        }
    });

    viewParent.addView(textView);
}

private void doValidate() {
    presCounter = 0;
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et_guess);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);

    currentWord = dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];


    if(editText.getText().toString().equals(currentWord)) {
        //Toast.makeText(GuessItActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent a = new Intent(GuessItActivity.this,BossFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
        editText.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(GuessItActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editText.setText("");
    }
    keys = shuffleArray(keys);
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(linearLayout, key, editText);
    }
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    timer.cancel();
    this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

```
 String a2z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
        String answer = "World";
        // lets assume you need 16 char to select from
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++) {
            chars.add(answer.charAt(i));

        }
        int dif = 16 - chars.size();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
            int ranIndex = rand.nextInt(a2z.length());
            chars.add(a2z.charAt(ranIndex));
        }

        Collections.sort(chars);
        System.out.println("nameArray2" + chars.toString());
```